# Why can't stream of streams be reduced un parallel ? / stream has already been operated upon or closed

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

#### Context

I've stumble upon a rather annoying problem : I've a program with a lot of data source that are able to stream the same type of elements and I want to "map" each availiable element in the program (element order doesn't matter).

Therefore I've tried to reduce my `Stream<Stream<T>> streamOfStreamOfT;` into a simple `Stream<T> streamOfT;` using `streamOfT = streamOfStreamOfT.reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat);`

Since element order is not important for me, I've tried to parallelize the reduce operation with a `.parallel()` : `streamOfT = streamOfStreamOfT.parallel().reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat);` But this triggers an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`

#### Example

To experience it yourself just play with the following main (java 1.8u20) by commenting / uncommenting the `.parallel()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // GIVEN
    List<Stream<Integer>> listOfStreamOfInts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        IntStream intStreamOf10Ints = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(10);
        Stream<Integer> genericStreamOf10Ints = StreamSupport.stream(
                intStreamOf10Ints.spliterator(), true);
        listOfStreamOfInts.add(genericStreamOf10Ints);
    }
    Stream<Stream<Integer>> streamOfStreamOfInts = listOfStreamOfInts
            .stream();
    // WHEN
    Stream<Integer> streamOfInts = streamOfStreamOfInts
            // ////////////////
            // PROBLEM
            //    |
            //    V
            .parallel()
            .reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat);

    // THEN
    System.out.println(streamOfInts.map(String::valueOf).collect(
            joining(", ")));
}
```

#### Question

Can someone explain this limitation  ? <strike>/ find a better way of handling parallel reduction of stream of streams</strike>

---

#### Edit 1

Following @Smutje and @LouisWasserman comments it seems that `.flatMap(Function.identity())` is a better option that tolerates `.parallel()` streams

Comment: Having a list of lists, you can `flatMap` it to a big list using streams...

Comment: You should definitely be using `flatMap` here.

Comment: @Smutje Ok, `flatMap` does the job but Still I don't understand `reduce` "reaction" to parallelisation

Comment: The part about "stream order is not important to me" is irrelevant; parallel reduction preserves order anyway (as long as your reduction operator is associative.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form of `reduce` you are using takes an identity *value* and an associative combining function.  But `Stream.empty()` is not a value; it has state.  Streams are not data structures like arrays or collections; they are carriers for pushing data through possibly-parallel aggregate operations, and they have some state (like whether the stream has been consumed or not.)  Think about how this works; you're going to build a tree where the same "empty" stream appears in more than one leaf.  When you try to use this stateful not-an-identity twice (which won't happen sequentially, but will happen in parallel), the second time you try and traverse through that empty stream, it will quite correctly be seen to be already used.

So the problem is, you're simply using this `reduce` method incorrectly.  The problem is not with the parallelism; it is simply that the parallelism exposed the underlying problem.

Secondly, even if this "worked" the way you think it should, you would only get parallelism building the tree that represents the flattened stream-of-streams; when you go to do the joining, that's a sequential stream pipeline there.  Ooops.

Thirdly, even if this "worked" the way you think it should, you're going to add a lot of element-access overhead by building up concatenated streams, and you're not going to get the benefit of parallelism that you are seeking.

The simple answer is to flatten the streams:

```
String joined = streamOfStreams.parallel()
                               .flatMap(s -> s)
                               .collect(joining(", "));
```

Comment: `.flatMap(s -> s)` can be expressed as `.flatMap(Function.identity())`